# помогите разобраться в классах php

Tags: php

Прошу знающих в php помочь, изучаю php, для меня вообще первый язык программирования, поэтому в процессе постоянно возникают настолько тупые вопросы, что интернет словно даже не отвечает на них. Дошел до классов и попал в некий ступор. Помогите разобраться.
Есть вот такой пример из учебника:

```
<?php ## Использование статических членов класса.
  class Counter
  {
    // Скрытый статический член класса - общий для всех объектов.
    private static $count = 0;
    // Конструктор увеличивает счетчик на 1. Обратите внимание
    // на синтаксис доступа к статическим переменным класса!
    public function __construct() { self::$count++; }
    // Деструктор же - уменьшает.
    public function __destruct() { self::$count--; }
    // Статическая функция, возвращает счетчик объектов.
    public static function getCount() { return self::$count; }
    // Как видите, установить счетчик в произвольное значение
    // извне нельзя, можно только получить его значение. Вот он,
    // модификатор private "в действии".
  }
  // Создаем 6 объектов.
  for ($objs = [], $i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) 
    $objs[] = new Counter();
  // Статические функции можно вызывать точно так же, как будто  
  // бы это - обычный метод объекта. При этом $this все равно
  // не передается, он просто игнорируется.
  echo "Сейчас существует {$objs[0]->getCount()} объектов.<br />"; 
  // Удаляем один объект.
  $objs[5] = null;
  // Счетчик объектов уменьшится!
  echo "А теперь - {$objs[0]->getCount()} объектов.<br />";
  // Удаляем все объекты.
  $objs = [];
  // Другой способ вызова статического метода - с указанием класса.
  // Это очень похоже на вызов функции из библиотеки.
  echo "Под конец осталось - ".Counter::getCount()." объектов.<br />"; 
?>
```

Начну с конца:

- $objs[0]->getCount() - почему указан 0?
- $objs[5] = null; - я так понимаю, что присваивается значение null пятому элементу в массиве $objs, но по факту, весь массив вроде бы отчищается, как это работает?
- $objs[] = new Counter(); - Я так понимаю создается массив $objs который использует класс Counter. Но что это значит? Как массив может быть равен классу, там же нет никакого точного значения. Только пара функций.
- public function __destruct() { self::$count--; } - как я понял, уменьшает $count на 1, но как он запускается?? Что приводит в действие эту функцию?
- public function __construct() { self::$count++; } - Тоже самое, только увеличивает счетчик на 1, вопрос тот же, что приводит в действие эту функцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $objs[0]->getCount() - почему указан 0?
> Потому что при записи

```
$objs[]
```

В массив добавляется элемент. Если не указывать ключ, то он добавляется по порядку в виде числа. Так как эта операция была произведена один раз, то ключом ячейки будет "0", откуда и достается элемент.

**заметка:** однако такой вызов не совсем корректен, т.к. идет попытка вызова статического метода в нестатическом контексте. До PHP7 это прокатит, а в поздних версиях нет. потому что это неправильно.

> $objs[5] = null; - я так понимаю, что присваивается значение null пятому элементу в массиве $objs, но по факту, весь массив вроде бы отчищается, как это работает?

Почему должен очиститься весь массив? Ведь тут же указана чётко ячейка с индексом 5.

> $objs[] = new Counter(); - Я так понимаю создается массив $objs который использует класс Counter. Но что это значит? Как массив может быть равен классу, там же нет никакого точного значения. Только пара функций.

Когда пишется

```
new Counter()
```

то создается экземпляр класса и помещается в некую переменную. В данном случае экземпляры создаются в цикле и складываются в ячейки массива. Поэтому в каждой ячейке лежит по экземпляру класса `Counter`

> public function __destruct() { self::$count--; } - как я понял, уменьшает $count на 1, но как он запускается?? Что приводит в действие эту функцию?

Например удаление объекта, как пример:

```
$objs[5] = null
```

или если данный объект больше не используется и GC решает его удалить как мусор. Например это может быть, если работа с объектом происходит в какой-нибудь функции/методе

```
function myMethod(){
    $counter = new Counter();
}
```

После отработки метода `myMethod` переменная `$counter` нигде не используется и убивается. Что вызвает деструктор

> public function __construct() { self::$count++; } - Тоже самое, только увеличивает счетчик на 1, вопрос тот же, что приводит в действие эту функцию?

Логично что создание объекта вызвает это, то есть вот эта строка:

```
new Counter()
```

Больше информации о магических методах, в которые входят `__construct` и `__destruct` написано в документации: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но не понял про $objs[0]->getCount()  ведь в примере показывается количество объектов, то есть как я понял, создалось 6 переменных в массиве, мы тут вызывает 0, и получаем количество 5, вместо 1? разве не должно быть $objs[]->getCount() ?

Comment: @PaulWall нет. я же написал, что в вашем случае объекты хранятся в ячейках массива. Значит, чтобы вызвать хоть какой-то метод у объекта, то надо в начале обратиться по индексу, например `$obj[3]` и вызвать у него метод `$obj[3]->someMethod`. А так как метод `getCount` возвращает статическую переменную, то она будет для всех экземпляров одинаковая и поэтому можно вызвать `getCount` на любом объекте. В данном случае это тот, что лежит в  ячейке "0"

Comment: аааааа все понял наконец-то =) а то нигде это не написано было))

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря у вас очень плохо с теорией, а еще с выбором первого языка программирования(для примера я бы рекомендовал какой-нибудь Python).
Объясню "на пальцах":

1. Статические переменные - переменные, которые существуют на
   протяжении работы всей программы, они хранят значение одно 
   для всех объектов класса(которое также можно и изменять), прочитать
   подробнее можно [тут](http://www.php.su/learnphp/vars/?statvars)
2. `null` - ключевое слово, которое занимается освобождением
   памяти, тем самым уничтожая элемент/ы массива
3. `$objs[] = new Counter()` - в цикле добавляет к массиву
   объект типа `Counter`
4. Конструктор вызывается при создании объекта, а деструкторы при
   уничтожении объекта, прочитать подробнее про них можно [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.decon.php)

Answer (score 1):

1) Вообще интересный способ вызова статической функции. Думаю при использовании где-то в реальных проектах будет создавать только непонятки (поскольку это функция класса и у объекта в реальности такого метода нету). Гораздо понятнее было бы делать вызов так `Counter::getCount()`.

2) Во первых, в данном случае "убивается" 6-й элемент (**нумерация массивов начинается с 0**). Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду под словом *отчищается*. Обычные массивы (а в php бывают еще и *ассоциативные*) визуально выглядят где-то так:

0 1 2 3 4 5    ---> индексы массивов

a b c d e f    ---> значения массивов

т.е. Вы, при обращении к **5** элементу получаете букву **f**, при обращении ко **2** - **c** и т.д. Можете смотреть на них как на полочку с ящиками для инструментов, где каждый ящик на полке подписан.

3) ключевое слово **new** создает новый **объект** класса *Counter*, который умеет делать и использовать то, что вы объявили в классе Counter без модификатора *static*. В данном примере в классе *Counter* нету не статических пользовательских методов (конструктор и деструктор являются, как бы правильно назвать...встроенными методами что ли). Попробуйте объявить свой метод в Вашем классе, например:

```
public function sayHello(){
    echo 'Hello!';
}
```

Тогда Вы сможете вызвать его на объекте (`objs[0]->sayHello()`, но не сможете вызвать в статическом контексте (`Counter::sayHello() //будет ошибка`).

4, 5) В данном месте используются операции **инкрементации** и **декрементации**. Почитать про данные операции можете, например, [здесь](http://info.javarush.ru/L2CCCP/2015/05/30/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.html).

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но если я создам паблик функцию и вызову ее, почему именно 0 указан в objs[0]->sayHello()

Comment: @PaulWall потому что так захотел автор книги, которую Вы читаете ;) На самом деле, Вы можете вызвать эту функцию (в контексте ооп - это метод) на любом объекте данного класса